# iTunes connect showing processing symbol

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, xcode7, archive

iTunes connect showing processing symbol after upload archive to app store
Hi ,
I Upload archive to app store and it successfully done, but in iTunes connect under Build its shows Build is processing and also I waited for 12hr , but still symbol showing processing.I tried again to upload but facing same problem
Note : I uploaded archive using Xcode 7 and also disable bitcode.
Please suggest me solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: yeah, facing same problem.
Last day I uploaded 3 times and after that today I uploaded 2 times then latest version is available for testing...
In-short the solution is that upload again and wait 30 - 45 mins if its still in processing the upload again.

Comment: Okay , If i am uploading again and again , is it create any any troubleshooting ?

Answer (score 1):

Processing can take some time.

If it's taking exceptionally long. More than a few hours, the usual way of fixing this is to just do another upload.

Unfortunately, this is all at Apples end.

Comment: more than few hour means? how much time i have to wait ?

Answer (score 0):

My app successfully uploaded in iTunes. actually I was using old Testflight SDK, I just remove it and my build successfully uploaded in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in our-company case was this:

"The builds you have recently attempted to deliver are not uploading completely or are being corrupted during the upload process."

There is/was something wrong with our network. Either some PORTS were not opened OR the file got corrupted during upload process.

Comment: nope , I tried and wait for two days. I just keep calm and tried to next day (3) and it uploaded successfully . Thanks for answering @sabiland

Comment: Yes, it took yesterday 10 hours for my build to go from Processing to OK.